# Exception with Computed Property on Ember Data Model using RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I have basically the following two models in an ember.js app using ember data and the RESTAdapter.

```
App.JobsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  completedCount: function() {
    return 0; //Doesn't matter what I return here.
  }.property('content.@each.state')
});

App.Job = DS.Model.extend({
  transactions: DS.hasMany('App.Transaction'),
  state: function() {
    return 0; //Doesn't matter what I do here
  }.property('transactions.@each.transactionType')
});

App.Transaction = DS.Model.extend({
  job: DS.belongsTo('App.Job'),
  transactionType: DS.attr('number')
});
```

The problem I'm having is the presence of the `transactions.@each.transactionType` causes the following exception:

`` "Attempted to handle event `becomeDirty` on <App.Transaction:ember462:1> while in state rootState.loaded.materializing.firstTime. Called with undefined" ``

I can't find any reference to this in the issue queue or anywhere else on stack overflow. What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

So I've done some more investigating and didn't make things clear enough in my original post. I've updated the code to reflect it.

1) It doesn't matter what I do inside the computed properties. Just having them causes the exception.

2) The exception only happens if there is another computed property which depends on the original. (Hope that makes sense)

So in the above example The JobsController has a computed property which is based on a computed property of the Job model.

Answer (score 0):

Try depending on isLoaded too:

```
state: function(){
  return this.get('isLoaded') ? this.get('transactions.lastObject.transactionType') : null;
}.property('isLoaded', 'transactions.@each.transactionType')
```

Comment: depending on isLoaded causes the same ``attempted to handle event becameDirty``exceptoin

Answer (score 0):

cause transactions is an Ember Array you should test is length to determine if he has data available ... try something like:

```
state: function(){
    var transactions = this.get('transactions');
    var lastObject = transactions.get('length') > 0 ? transactions.get('lastObject') : null;
    return lastObject !== null ? lastObject.get('transactionType') : null;
}.property('transactions.@each.transactionType')
```

Comment: see my updated question. What I'm doing inside the property isn't whats causing the error, just having the dependent computed properties causes the problem

Comment: have you try using model instead of content ? .property('model.@each.state')